# Where does the extra attributes and markup come from in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is the actual HTML code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon document item-left></ion-icon>
  <h2>Overview</h2>
  <p class="item-description">{{movie.overview}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

This is what I get in browser after calling `ionic serve`:

```
<ion-item class="item item-block item-md">
   <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <!--template bindings={
        "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
        }-->
        <ion-label class="label label-md">
            <h2>Overview</h2>
            <p class="item-description">A lot of text that should extend to multiple lines.</p>
        </ion-label>
      </div>
      <!--template bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
      }-->
    </div>
    <div class="button-effect">
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Are there any rules that determine what the final markup will look like? How can I style the elements if I don't know what should I exactly assign style rules to? For example, this is the default CSS of `ion-label`:

```
.ion-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This causes the text to be just limited to a single line. There was no way for me to beforehand(I guess) that ionic will wrap the text in a label. How could I override the style then?

My two questions are: Why does the initial and final markup look different? Is there any way to determine what the final markup will look like?